# nuxt 3 error with scss vars register, how to fix?

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, vite

Trying to register index.scss (which include vars, sass installed as devDeps), but getting error
when use var in any files:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [postcss] [sass] Undefined variable.
  ╷
5 │   background-color: $--ui-elems-color;
  │   

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  builder: "vite",
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiUrl: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    },
  },
  alias: {
    "~": __dirname,
    "@components": "./components",
    "@assets": "./assets",
  },
  plugins: [],
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["@element-plus/nuxt", "@pinia/nuxt", "@vueuse/nuxt"],
  vite: {
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: '@forward "@assets/scss/index.scss";', // tried @use, @import - nothing work.
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

index.scss

```
@use "./_vars.scss";
```

File paths is correct.

Here is strucutre:

[image]